# Django/python model form type error

Tags: python, django, sqlite, typeerror

I am getting a `quote_from_bytes() expected bytes` error when I am following the Django documentation for using Model form. It appears to write to the SQLite DB but every time I fill out the form it gives this error. I am running Django version 2.0.2 and Python version 3.5.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *
class inputforms(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Inputform
    fields = ['auditid', 'audittask', 'responsibleperson', 'auditstatus', 'auditnotes', 'auditdate']
```

**views.py**

```
def inputview(request):

    form = inputforms(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse, 'auditpage')

    args = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'auditentry.html', args)
```

**models.py**

```
class Inputform(models.Model):
auditid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
audittask = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
responsibleperson = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
auditstatus = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
auditnotes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
auditdate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'inputform'
```

**traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/PycharmProjects/project/audit/views.py", line 15, in inputview
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse, 'auditpage')
File "/home/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 407, in __init__
self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
File "/home/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 151, in iri_to_uri
return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/parse.py", line 712, in quote
return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/parse.py", line 737, in quote_from_bytes
raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Comment: Django version? Python version? Full traceback of the error? What's with the commented-out line? Have you tried limiting your model/form to just one field, to find the offending field (if any)?

Comment: @Evert I updated my questions with the missing details. I also removed that commented line of code as it was something I saw to try but should have nothing to do with my current configuration.

Comment: @Evert I tried every field individually in the fields variable list on the form and it still gives the error.

Comment: Well, they are all TextFields, so that'd make sense. Can you post the traceback for completeness as well?

Comment: The traceback shows the problem to be at `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse, 'auditpage')` in your code. But, you have not shown us the definition of `reverse`. Perhaps there is your problem?

Comment: @Evert reverse is being called from from django.urls import reverse I thought for sending the user back to the same page they filled out the form.

Comment: `reverse` is a *function*: you're passing it as an argument to `HttpResponseRedirect`, and the second argument is just ignored. Please read up on the correct usage of `reverse`.

Comment: @Evert Ah I see. Thank you for that clarification. I removed that and it posts to the DB and I no longer get the error.

Answer (score 0):

As Evert noted in the comments, I do not need the reverse function as it is calling it as an argument. Removing this line of code allowed my form to work without any errors.